# Rundeck - User Group Source Plugins - Java Plugin Type

Tags: rundeck

I want to understand the use case/usage of "User Group Source Plugins - Java Plugin Type"

1) can I use the plugin's returned roles/groups in authorization policies(/etc/rundeck/myadmin.aclpolicy)

---

2) what is the property and its value of this plugin, I should mention here?
framework.plugin.UserGroupSource.[your_plugin_name].[property]=value
In below case, framework.plugin.UserGroupSource.example-user-group-source-plugin.[property]=value

---

3) Can I connect to a RDBMS and get the roles from DB using java class constuctor

package example;

````
@Plugin(name = "example-user-group-source-plugin",service= ServiceNameConstants.UserGroupSource)
public class ExampleUserGroupSourcePlugin implements UserGroupSourcePlugin {
    List<String> groups = new ArrayList<>();

    public ExampleUserGroupSourcePlugin() {
        groups.add("RUNDECK_USER"); //This group would get added to all users
        //TODO: DBConnect code to get roles from RDBMS
    }
    @Override
    public List<String> getGroups(final String username, final Map<String, Object> config) {
        //some code 
        return groups;
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, the ACL definition can take the roles defined in your plugin. In the same way which LDAP roles for example.
2. What you define in your code as you see [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/blob/15921338616cb939fa6d0f1ddaf6fc4f74d5c5c8/examples/example-java-execution-lifecyle-plugin/src/main/java/org/rundeck/example/plugin/ExecutionLifeCycleTestPlugin.java#L42) (maybe the documentation needs some update to specify that).
3. Theoretically yes, using the right way to connect to DB like [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/steps-to-connect-to-the-database-in-java).